# Custom TimeZone in MySQLi Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli

I am android developer and working one API with PHP to use in my android application. I do not know PHP language. I have query in which I want update datetime field of database. its working fine with qu_time=Now() but I want set my timezone to field qu_time. My current query is like below

```
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=1, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() where _quid=$x ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
```

I have got one function which is converting time to my timezone but I have no idea how can I use it. That function is like below

```
function getDatetimeNow() {
    $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
    //date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');

 $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Anyone can please suggest me how can I use it with my above query or there any other way to set my timezone with update query ?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: You need to know that using string interpolation into SQL queries, like this... `where _quid=$x`... is an extremely dangerous and completely unacceptable practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current query you are using `Now()` which is mysql function. IF you want to use php according to your function then use below code

```
    $qu_time = getDatetimeNow();
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=1, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time='$qu_time' where _quid=$x ORDER BY _quid ASC ");

    function getDatetimeNow() {
        $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
        //date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');

        $datetime = new DateTime();
        $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
        return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getDatetimeNow($existed_time) {// pass your variable 
    $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
    //date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');

    $datetime = $existed_time; // assign it to $datetime variable
    $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object); 
    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```